# keeping track of push notifications while in background Swift

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to listen for a push notification while the app is running in the background.  This is because when the app re enters the foreground I need it to update a counter of how many push notifications I received while I was in the background.  Now when you click the push notification it brings you back to the app and updates fine,  however if you press the home button receive a push notification and then reopen the background app manually the notification data is lost.  How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my problem I added 'content-available' => 1